# Image not displaying in Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Am working on my first Rails app, and cannot get my image file (logo.png) to display in the browser at the localhost:3000/pages/home page. The image is held in the public/images/logo.png file in my Rails app. Any idea why it might not be showing?

Here is the code:

application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title><%= title %></title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/screen', :media => 'screen' %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/print', :media => 'print' %>
    <!--[if lt IE 8]><%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/ie' %><![endif]-->
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'custom', :media => 'screen' %>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="container">
                <header>
                    <%= image_tag("logo.png", :alt => "Sample App", :class => "round") %>
                    <nav class="round">
                        <ul>
                            <li><%= link_to "Home", '#' %></li>
                            <li><%= link_to "Help", '#' %></li>
                            <li><%= link_to "Sign in", '#' %></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </header>
                <section class="round">
                    <%= yield %>
                </section>
            </div>

            </div>      
        </body>
</html>
```

Added source in container  in :

```
<div class="container">
                <header>
                    <img alt="Sample App" class="round" src="/images/logo.png" />
                    <nav class="round">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sign in</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </header>
                <section class="round">


        <h1>Sample App</h1>
        <p>
            This is the home page for the 
            <a href="http://railstutorial.org">Ruby on Rails Tutorial</a>
            sample application.
        </p>

        <a href="#" class="signup_button round">Sign up now!</a>

                </section>
            </div>

            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you will need to specify the link like 
    "/images/logo.png"
or there are also ways to create short path rules if the images is used more often

Comment: Hmmm... I just changed the path to "/images/logo.png" and hit "Reload" in the browser and nothing happened. Any suggestions? TIA

Comment: ya... what do u see in you html output...is there an <img> tag in there? and if there is, what does src link to?

Comment: Yes, there is an image tag, and the source is pointing to "images/logo.png". I have pasted in the code from the container div above in a  new edit. TIA

Comment: its actually pointing to "/images/logo.png"... i guess it should point to just "images/logo.png"

Comment: i mean if u can see the picture by going to http://localhost:3000/images/logo.png on the browser, u should also be able to see it from "images/logo.png"

Comment: FOUND THE PROBLEM. For some reason, the logo.png image file did not copy over. So I recopied the file over, and it displayed OK in the browser. Now it works. Sorry for all the trouble and thanks for your help.

Comment: I just wanted to add, I was doing <%= image_tag '563456-34564356-3456346.jpg' %> and it was not working so I figured it must be a directory structure or syntax issue and searched all over the place.  I renamed the image to poodle.jpg and it works great now. doh!

Answer (score 0):

In regular views you can access images in the public/assets/images directory like this:

```
<%= image_tag "rails.png" %>
```